# OnSave Javascript for CRM 2011 quote product

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an script on the quote product which I want to update the tax value when saving the form. But, it did update the tax according previous values of the fields. The script is as:

```
function tax ()
{
   var val0 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").getValue();
   var val1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("manualdiscountamount").getValue();
   val2 = val0 - val1;
   val2 = val2 * 0.05;
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("tax").setValue(val2);
}
```

For example, if the base amount is 10 and the manual discount is 1 on the create of the quote product, then the tax updates to 0. If after save, I change the base amount to 20 and manual discount is 1, then the tax is updated to 0.45! Mean that, it calculates the tax based on the previous values of the fields!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you get the `baseamount` value before CRM updates it.

`baseamout` is calculated after the form is saved, so you need to calculate the value by hands as this simplified example:

```js
function tax ()
{
   var priceperunit = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("priceperunit").getValue();
   var quantity = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("quantity").getValue();
   var val0 = priceperunit * quantity;
   var val1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("manualdiscountamount").getValue();
   val2 = val0 - val1;
   val2 = val2 * 0.05;
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("tax").setValue(val2);
}
```

pay attention that there is also the field for volume discount and the product can be also a write-in.

Comment: The same goes for the volume discount. It is calculated after the save operation, hence I could not use it!

Comment: I pointed deliberately to the volume discount field, some companies don't use built-in discount lists so make more easy the customization. If they use the discount list, I will try first with a plugin, if they want "real time" values is necessary to realize an heavy customization, including change the default save buttons and a save-reload form mechanism.